# Reinversing permutation in a table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, permutation

Imagine I have the following table:

```
----------------
 ID   f1     f2
----------------
 A   1001   5001
 B   1001   5001
 B   1001   5002
 B   1002   5001
 B   1002   5002
 C   1001   5003
 C   1001   5004
```

(all the possible permutations of f1 and f2 for each ID is present)
is there any query that gives me this?

```
A   1001
A   5001
B   1001
B   1002
B   5001
B   5002
C   1001
C   5003
C   5004
```

all the distinct values of f1 and f2 for each ID
thank you.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply` without using `union all` :

```
select distinct t.id, f_val
from table t cross apply
     ( values (f1), (f2) ) tt(f_val)
order by t.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.ID, s.f
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ID, f1 UNION ALL SELECT ID, f2) AS s(ID, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below query will help you.

```
create
table test(ID 
char(1),f1
int, f2 
int)
insert
into test values('A',1001,5001),('B',
 1001, 5001),('B', 1001, 5002),('B',
 1002, 5001),('B', 1002, 5002),('C',1001,5003),('C',1001,5004)
 
Select
distinct ID, f 
from (Select ID, f1
as f From test 
union select ID, f2
as f from test) ff
```